# Restrict selection of few dates in jQuery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, html

Following code is intended to restrict selection of today's date in datepicker.

```
    jQuery(function () {

        var dateModifier = {
            beforeShowDay: function (dd) {
                var today = new Date();
                if (dd.getDate() === today.getDate()) {
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        };

        jQuery("#txt1").datepicker(dateModifier);

    });
```

For this purpose I have explicity passed `dateModifier` object, containing `beforeShowDay` event. I read on jQuery doc that this event is fired for all the dates shown in calender. When we return `false`, `dd` date would be disabled.

However this code disables all the dates. What am I missing.

**HTML:**

```
<input id="txt1" type="text" name="name" value=" " />
```

Comment: Cander <-> Calander, what is that???   You should edit your question so that will help futur people whose search for jquery CALENDAR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var disabledDays = ["9-21-2010", "9-24-2010", "9-27-2010", "9-28-2010", "9-3-2010", "9-17-2010", "9-2-2010", "9-3-2010", "9-4-2010", "9-5-2010"];
function disableAllTheseDays(date) {
    var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
        if($.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1) {
            return [false];
        }
    }
    return [true];
}

var dateModifier = {
        beforeShowDay: disableAllTheseDays
    };

    jQuery("#txt1").datepicker(dateModifier);
```

Check [here](http://articles.tutorboy.com/2010/09/03/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-specified-dates/) for some more

Comment: Thanks, IMO comparing dates by creating `Array of dates` for the restricted date would be better than comparing strings,   as in `$.inArray((m+1) + '-' + d + '-' + y,disabledDays) != -1`. What do you say ?